# Initializing segments of an Eigen VectorXd

Tags: c++, eigen

I'd like to efficiently initialize segments of an VectorXd object from the Eigen library. This vector is large (~1e6) so I would like to do this efficiently. Below is an example showing what I was thinking.

```
size_t N = 1e6;
std::vector<double> F(1., 2., 3., 4.);
Eigen::VectorXd ln_f_origin( F.size() * num_B );
for (size_t i=0; i<F.size(); i++) {
    ln_f_origin.segment(i*num_B, num_B) = log(F[i]/num_B);
}
```

This doesn't seem to be working. I'm getting the following error:

```
error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1> >::FixedSegmentReturnType<-1>::Type' {aka 'Eigen::VectorBlock<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1>, -1>'} and 'double')
```

Comment: I think you are missing `.array()` before you can do this kind of operation.

Comment: Yes, I think you might be right. I will need this to be a VectorXd eventually, I guess I can just convert to an array and back again. I would prefer if I didn't have to do this. Maybe there is a better way to do what I want to do?

Comment: @Alex `.array()` is a zero-cost view on the underlying `Vector` (or segment). An alternative is to use `ln_f_origin.segment(i*num_B, num_B).setConstant(log(F[i]/num_B);`

Comment: Also, storing a lot of the same value is likely not the most efficient solution overall -- maybe also show what you intend to do with `ln_f_origin` afterwards.

Comment: `ln_f_origin` is subtracted from a different vector `ln_f`. It's probably not the most efficient, but the rest of the code is already very computationally intensive (e.g. other parts of the code involve Poisson relaxation and a few hundred million binary searches), and this is a drop in the bucket compared to that. I may change it when I actually start profiling the code, but it's fine for now.